# Why won't onDraw() resume after powering down/locking device?

Tags: android

*EDIT* I am by no means experienced with android; this is my first application!

I'm trying to draw a sprite on-screen and move it across the screen.
When I press the home button and then back to the application, the drawing stops and continues as expected, but when I press the power button or lock button, the drawing process stops altogether. Could someone give me some clarification on how I should handle this? Thanks.

This is the code:

```
package com.MB2Assignment.assignment;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.graphics.Paint.Align;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class Graphics extends Activity{

    boolean drawEnabled = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);



        //myView = new CustomView(this);
        setContentView(new FallingMan(this));

    }

    public class FallingMan extends View {

        Bitmap charStand;
        float changingY;
        Typeface font;

        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        Rect middleRect = new Rect();
        Paint colorBlue = new Paint();


        public FallingMan(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            charStand = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.charstand);
            changingY = 0;
            font = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "font.tff");
            //drawEnabled = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onDraw(canvas);



            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);

            textPaint.setARGB(50, 0, 0, 0);
            textPaint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            textPaint.setTextSize(50);
            textPaint.setTypeface(font);
            canvas.drawText("Behold, The Falling Man", canvas.getWidth()/2, 200, textPaint);

            canvas.drawBitmap(charStand, canvas.getWidth()/2, changingY, null);

            if(drawEnabled == true)
            {
                if (changingY < canvas.getHeight()) changingY += 10;
                else changingY = 0;


                middleRect.set(0,400,canvas.getWidth(),550);

                colorBlue.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                canvas.drawRect(middleRect, colorBlue);

                invalidate();
            }
        }   

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onBackPressed();
        drawEnabled = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        drawEnabled = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        drawEnabled = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onStop();
        drawEnabled = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
    }



}
```

Comment: Was your activity destroyed??

Comment: I'm not sure. I tried running the app with the onDestroy() functions commented out... same results.

Comment: why comment that. isntead log info in that an check the log

Comment: I'm not experienced with this. I thought that line had something to do with it. I can't find anything in Logcat that suggest anything was destroyed. If there is another log you're talking about, I'd be delighted with an explanation if it would help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The error was that 'invalidate();' was inside the wrong pair of brackets. It has to be within the 'onDraw()' scope.